# In Python 3 when i have error in create new label Button

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

I am using Tkinter in python 3 and sqlite3 I create a registration form having two buttons and text label I am opening a new window after clicking on the sign in the button when I am creating another b\utton in signing window getting error

```
def new_winF():
    newwin = Toplevel(root)
    newwin.geometry('500x500')
    # display = Label(newwin, width=70, height=80)
    label_zero = Label(newwin, text="SignIn form", width=20, font=("bold", 20))
    label_zero.place(x=90, y=63)
    label_one = Label(newwin, text="Email", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
    label_one.place(x=80, y=130)
    label_one = Entry(newwin, textvar=Email)
    label_one.place(x=240, y=130)

    label_two = Label(newwin, text="Password", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
    label_two.place(x=80, t=180)
    label_two = Entry(newwin)
    label_two.place(x=240, y=180)
    buttonSignIn = Button(root, text="Sign in", width=10, bg='black', fg='white', command=new_winF).place(
    x=140, y=430)
```

Comment: label_two = Entry(newwin) i am getting error here on debugging

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error. It's impossible to read when it's in the comments.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps that is due to error in line:

```
label_two.place(x=80, t=180)
```

Probably should be:

```
label_two.place(x=80, y=180)
```

As there is no option t in place() method.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm

Comment: + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-t"

Comment: @rammohandubey we know `t` is causing the error. If you read Bartosz answer he is telling you to change `t` to a `y`... Its that simple.

Comment: @rammohandubey: this is _definitely_ the problem.

Comment: sorry, I did not see that time I appropriate your answer thank you, sir !